# How to discover GET/POST parameters used in URL during pentest?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, xss

Is there a good/systematic way to discover the `GET`/`POST` parameters used in the URL?

For example, I want to discover the parameter names `a`, `b`, `c` used in the URLs

```
https://myserver/index.php?a=10
https://myserver/index.php?b=test
https://myserver/index.php?c=hello
```

Answer (score 1):

you can only discover parameters used by developer and serving to you, in this case if you want to discover all GET/POST parameter of the page you should analyse the code of this page, no way to discover all parameters after compile.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the page.

If this is a form, then when analyzing the page you will see which parameters are sent back to the backend.

If this is a standalone access point (like an API), then there is no way (beside the documentation) to guess how the developer designed his `POST`, `GET`, etc. calls. You could extrapolate from some of his code you would happen to know and hope he is consistent, but this is just wild guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Great way is to use Burp Suite and Param Miner extension https://portswigger.net/bappstore/17d2949a985c4b7ca092728dba871943
It doesn't need Professional version of Burp Suite. The extension can guess GET/POST/JSON/XML parameters, headers, cookies, and it's very fast. It supports custom wordlists and much more.